# What is "Hill-Climb Traversal" in the context of doubly linked lists?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15563676/14857940) S.O. answer, the user claims that an advantage of doubly linked lists over singly linked lists is that they allow you to perform "Hill-Climb Traversal". What does this mean?

The only interpretation I can think of is as follows: start from the head, and and instead of moving only forwards like in a singly linked list, move 1 forward, 1 back, 1 forward, 1 back, etc. However, this doesn't seem to be any better than the simple transversal of a singly linked list.